# Footer Content Align

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage I am working on for a school project. Here is the jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/adamkerik/6c17ajqa/

```
<footer>
<div class="social-container">
    <ul class="social-icons">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--text-->
<h1>Follow Us</h1>
<div class="uzex">
<div class="vr"></div>
<ul>
<li><strong>Contact Us</strong></li>
<li>3678 Poe Road</li>
<li>Mount Pleasant, South Carolina 29464</li>
<li>843-216-9434</li>
</ul>
</div>
</footer>
```

The problem is that on the footer of the page, I want the content to be centered with the "div class va" in the middle of the buttons and the list. I just cant seem to get the content centered. Thanks for any help!

ps the css is in the jsfiddle page, cause i know that will probably be needed

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your footer element CSS:

```
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
 text-align:center;
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6c17ajqa/6/

Comment: While this helps to center my content vertically, I needed more of a horizontal center with the buttons on the left of the va class div and the list on the right, all of that centered within the middle of the div. Your answer is much appreciated though, thank you. @Tom

Answer (score 0):

You need to make this container to be center.

```
  .social-container {
      width: 400px;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 6;
      margin: 0 auto;
      left:50%;
      top: 60%;
      transform:translate(-50%, -50%)
    }
```

Follow the link of fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jb7f2mwy/

Comment: Many thanks. I previously just readjusted everything into tables and made the borders pertain to how I wanted the vertical lines. Your answer is most certainly appreciated though.